# How to produce electricity with mechanical power/spring coil

Tags: power, design, components, diy, mechanical

As a home project I want to make a electricity generator which uses a spring coil, which when turned/wound(just like the mechanism in wrist watches) enough times will start unwinding and generate power small/large enough to power a small bulb/ night light / LED.

The entire assembly should be handy/easy to carry around.

Can you guys give some ideas? some online DIY project reference ?

Pls feel free to add/remove relevant/irrelevant tags.

Comment: First figure out how much energy you can store in that spring. Then, figure out how much energy you need to run a small bulb/night light/LED. Then dismay as you realize that the latter is much larger than the former.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, thanx for reply, I was very impressed by this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanically_powered_flashlight

Comment: The problem isn't putting in the required energy. *That* problem was solved a very, very long time ago. The issue is trying to store it in a spring.

Comment: Tri state Led powered by a stepper motor, with a speed control spun by a spring. It may run down in a very short time, like an alarm on a wind up clock.

Comment: Look up clockwork generator on Google and read the following.  There are lots of examples.   -   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_power#Windup_radio

Comment: and just in case you think you'll make your fortune http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2280057/Im-living-poverty-Inventor-wind-radio-calls-stronger-patent-laws-carved-profits-gadget.html